# Is it possible to use a readonly struct as a owned entity in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I want to use a Password struct instead of using two properties called `PasswordHash` and `PasswordSalt` (I still want those as a column on the users table). But I can't seem to find a way to implement it with EF Core.

```cs
public class User
{
    /* other properties */

    public Password Password { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public readonly struct Password
    : IEquatable<Password>
{
    public string Hash { get; }
    public string Salt { get; }

    public Password(string hash, string salt)
    {
        Hash = hash;
        Salt = salt;
    }

    public bool Equals(Password other)
    {
        return Hash == other.Hash && Salt == other.Salt;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return obj is Password other && Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Hash, Salt);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Password left, Password right) => left.Equals(right);
    public static bool operator !=(Password left, Password right) => !left.Equals(right);
}
```

I know it works if I do it like this:

```cs
public record Password(string Hash, string Salt);
```

However, I want it to use `readonly` properties. The idea is that you are forced to change both the hash and salt when updating the password. It's not for security but more for abstraction and cleaner code.

I tried using the `OwnsOne` method.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
    {
        entity.OwnsOne(navigationExpression: u => u.Password, buildAction: navigationBuilder =>
        {
            navigationBuilder.Property(p => p.Salt).HasColumnName("PasswordSalt");
            navigationBuilder.Property(p => p.Hash).HasColumnName("PasswordHash");
        });
    });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: EF Core 8 supports both immutable record and struct constructs, I'm not sure they work with Owned, but realistically a Password made up of a Hash + Salt is a use case for a complex type which are supported rather than an Owned relation. See ("Immutable Record" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from Steve Py:

> EF Core 8 supports both immutable record and struct constructs, I'm not sure they work with Owned, but realistically a Password made up of a Hash + Salt is a use case for a complex type which are supported rather than an Owned relation. See ("Immutable Record" in [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#value-objects-using-complex-types))